# Javascript .focus() not working

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble getting the javascript .focus() function to work. At this point, I'm really not sure why it's failing to execute. Could it have something to do with onload?

This is my code:

```
var request_brochure = function()

{
    var name = $("name").value;
    var email = $("email").value;
    var isValid = true;

    if(name == "")
    {
        $("name").focus();
        alert("Please fill in your name.");
        $("name").focus();
        isValid = false;
    }
    else if(email == "")
    {
        window.setTimeout(function(){$("email").focus();}, 100);

        alert("Please fill in your email. ");
        window.setTimeout(function(){$("email").focus();}, 100);
        isValid = false;
    }

    if(isValid)
    {
        $("form_b").submit();
        //$("brochure").innerHTML = "Request Submitted";
    }
}

window.onload = function () {   
    $("name").focus();
    $("submit1").onclick = request_brochure;

}
var $ = function (id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem?

Comment: Why did you remove all the code?

Comment: Not to mention the question about `onload` makes no sense without the code.

Comment: You are doing it very wrong. Imagine you could solve this problem within 10 seconds if you were using jquery. Anyway, you can't go further without jquery. Learn it, it's easy!

Comment: @bad_boy jQuery makes it easier but it prevents you from learning more!

Comment: It works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/vnaw7s0j/1/. Are you sure you have IDs in your input elements, not just names?

Comment: I want to have a firm understanding of js before i start coding jquery. I know it would be simpler with it.

Comment: @Vohuman sure, but she needs a working solution, not learning curve

Comment: @bad_boy I would advocate the OP's decision to learn vanilla JS. The last thing we need is more *"JavaScript"* (jQuery) developers.

Comment: Ok then it's not how you should be learning. At the time, you don't  understand basic things, so if you need a working solution grab a copy of jquery, otherwise you will be implementing your solution about a week or even more

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the event isn't binding correctly. `window.onload` does not ensure the element with id `submit_1` is loaded. try adding the event to the button directly:

`<input id="submit_1" onclick="request_brochure()" />`

if that works then your problem is just that. Without jQuery you could mostly get away with binding the event by putting `$("submit1").onclick = request_brochure;` in a `<script>` at the end of the page, but results will be mixed from browser to browser. I'd really recommend using `jQuery(function () { $("submit1").onclick = request_brochure; })` and leaving the heavy lifting of determining when the page is completely loaded to the library, since it's been tried and tested for years and is much less likely to fail than a native approach.

The comments on your question have a lot of truth, and I'd hate to see you go down the path of jQuery's high level stuff designed to make non-programmers and programmers with little javascript knowledge live's easier. With that said, the browser landscape is quite the jungle, with more than half of the world on IE 8 or lower (I could be wrong about that by now, but I'm sure it's still a considerable amount), jQuery's low level stuff (like `$.ajax`, `$(function () {})` and the sizzle selector engine) is indispensable in my opinion. The main purposes of these utilities (jQuery's low level functions) is to address browser fragmentation issues and make devs live's easier. It's good to know the underlying code, but I'll take $.ajax over any implementation of HttpXmlRequest in a heartbeat (I still remember the days of IE6's activeX component... those were dark times). just don't do `$('#some-form-field').val()` without first learning `document.getElementById('some-form-field').value` and you should be fine :)

Comment: Instead of loading jQuery(_for the ready event_) one can also use the https://github.com/ded/domready

Comment: @Vohuman Yeah, but jquery is better anyway, because she will need  AJAX and effects or even bootstrap later

Comment: and that's beside the point. One should learn to program javascript while using tools that help avoid browser eccentricities (like the element-not-loaded-even-when-running-code-below-declaration nonsense) and fragmentation issues

Comment: It looks like it works, but it only focuses for a second and disappears. I'm pretty sure it has to do with the onload...

Comment: could you post a trace? (what alerts get fired?). Also, there's no need to focus the element twice. Only do it after the alert.

Comment: According to the stack trace, everything is being executed. It is executed in this order -  1. form.js()form.js (line 20)2.$("email").focus();3.isValid = false;

Comment: that can't be the order in which this code executes. `$("email").focus()` executes within a timeout, so it should run after `isValid` is set to `false`